# .htaccess: Disable hotlinking (via redirect)

Tags: flash, redirect, hotlinking

I am hosting a site that has some flash in it.
Now a different site is linking directly to the flash, causing massive traffic for me. The problem: I do not gain any ads which would help me pay the server bills.
I thought it would be OK to redirect the direct link to the flash to the site containing it.

Flash: www.example.com/flash/1.swf
Page: www.example.com/1 (<-- redirect here!)

It probably should work with .htacess, but I have no idea how. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: I have no complete answer, but you probably need to check the Referer header.

Comment: Another option is to discourage that site from hotlinking - don't redirect the hotlink requests. Instead, serve up something else. A small little .swf that says "you're stealing from mysite.com. Here's a picture of a festering gangrenous foot for your viewing pleasure".

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www\.example\.com
RewriteRule /flash/(.+)?\.swf$ www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```